# MSSQL to MYSQL conversion (.file) to (.sql)

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I had recently exported a MSSQL database dump file from Qualispace Windows hosting. The file has been downloaded as .(file) extension. I need to import that file to MYSQL and view database structure.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: that's not a usual file extension for a SQL backup or script. Have you tried opening the file in a text editor? Perhaps it's actually a SQL script. But even if it is, unless you specified the right compatibility options, it's unlikely to run directly in MySQL (and even then YMMV depending exactly what it contains). You need to google how to migrate between the two systems, it isn't as simple as this.

Comment: you said it is a SQL script, but the file is 900mb+. No text/code editors are supported for opening that huge file.

Comment: no I didn't say it was a SQL script. I said it _might_ be. But now you've mentioned the file size, it's quite unlikely. Unless it was a SQL dump of all the data and the database was very large. It's just as likely to be a .bak file or something. It's strange that the webhost set it to have that file extension, it's very unhelpful. You should check in the hosting settings or docs or whatever as to what file format gets exported. The file extension by itself does not determine the actual format of the data.

Comment: BTW it is possible to find a text editor that will open very large files: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=text+editor+that+can+open+1gb+file&oq=Text+editor+1GB+fil&aqs=chrome.2.0j69i57j0.4744j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: yeah. but, i need all that data. In hosting they didn't provide any information regarding file type.

Comment: Then you'll have to work it out. If it's a bak file, you'll be able to restore it into a another SQL server instance. If it's a SQL script, you'll be able to open it in a suitable text editor. If it's something else, you'll have to ask the webhost what it is and what they expect you to do with it. They really should have got this documented somewhere, or their support people should be able to tell you. We can only guess because we can't see it. Either you have to figure it out, or you have to ask the people who produced it.

Comment: Whichever it is, it isn't directly importable into MySQL. You'll have to do some additional work to achieve that. You can google if there are any existing tools around which can help you.

Answer (score -1):

You Can't Do That ™

You need an export in csv or sql format.

Look up how to migrate data from SQL Server to MySQL.